# NGINX serving wrong location when query string is added to the url

Tags: nginx

My goal is to serve the backend application under `/api` and the frontend at `/`

This configuration almost works, if I try to access any `/api` route with any kind of query string, my frontend application is getting the request and not the backend. Without the query string in the request, the backend is handling the request.

```
server {
    root /var/www/backend/public;

    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name incis.in;

    location / {
        root /var/www/frontend;
        
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$query_string;
    }


    location /api {
        root /var/www/backend/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
    }

    location /images {
        root /var/www/backend/public;
    }

    location /storage {
        root /var/www/backend/public;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/incis.in/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/incis.in/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}


server {
    if ($host = incis.in) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name incis.in;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are missing the `?` before `$query_string` in the `try_files` statement. Use: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;`

Comment: @RichardSmith OMG!!! Thank you!! Took 2 days to figure this out.